# Where is the process model designed in Activiti-Explorer saved?

Tags: alfresco, activiti, bpmn

I am using activiti explorer to create and edit process model diagram but need to know where this diagrams are stored by activiti-explorer ?

Thanks for any guidance

Comment: What version of Activiti are you using? It differs!

Comment: I am having activiti 5.15.1 version. @Gagravarr

Answer (score 1):

It would be stored in the database you configured when installing Activiti.  If you didn't configure a database, it's probably using h2 (see: https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#supporteddatabases)

Comment: i can see table in mysql activiti schema  but not sure in which table process model files are stored , there is a table 'act_re_model' which contains name of process model but i want to know that in which table which column this diagram bpmn.xml is stored?@Curtis this details i can not see in documentation

Comment: You may have a process_model table containing the BPMN in a CLOB or try the act_ge_bytearray table for a byte representation